# An example of curves with the same Jacobian, but different Jacobian automorphism groups (wrt their respective canonical principal polarizations)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, automorphism-groups, jacobians

I am trying to understand examples of differing curves with the same Jacobian, and the quirks of the Jacobian.

**Here is my question:**  What is an example where $Aut(Jac(X, a))$ and $Aut(Jac(X', a'))$ differ but $Jac(X) = Jac(X')$?

Here, $a$ and $a'$ denote the canonical principle polarizations associated to the (smooth, projective and geometrically integral) curves $X$ and $X'$ respectively. Let's say the base field is $\mathbb{C}$.

I have only found an example where $X$ and $X'$ are not isomorphic, $Jac(X)  = Jac(X')$, but $Aut(Jac(X, a)) = Aut(Jac(X', a'))$.

That example was from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0304471.pdf) of E. Howe:

$X: 3y^2 = (2x^2- 2)(16x^4 + 28x^2 + 1)$, and

$X': -y^2 = (2x^2 + 2)(16x^4 + 12x^2 + 1)$.